# What is Code Сhallenge in query param in authorization server like IdentityServer (from JS SPA client pov)?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

When I do manual redirect, I'm getting an error from IdentityServer

> invalid_request, code challenge required

[image]

However when I use [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library for the same authorization request, I do not get that error. Library somehow sets **code challenge** under the hood.

Here is me JS code.

Set up:

```js
const config = {
  authority: "https://demo.identityserver.io",
  client_id: "interactive.confidential",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback",
  response_type: "code",
  scope:"openid profile email api offline_access",
  post_logout_redirect_uri : "http://localhost:3000/post_logout",
};

const url = `https://demo.identityserver.io/connect/authorize?
client_id=${config.client_id}&
redirect_uri=${config.redirect_uri}&
response_type=${config.response_type}&
scope=${config.scope}`;
```

My manual authorization redirect request that throws:

```js
const onFormSubmit = async (ev: React.FormEvent) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace(url); // I simply do replace
}
```

Code with the library that doesn't throw:

```js
import Oidc from 'oidc-client';

const onFormSubmit = async (ev: React.FormEvent) => {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
  mgr.signinRedirect(); // login redirect here, no errors
}
```

I want to understand what **code challenge**m is. And how it gets generated. Give me a hint what to read about it.

I ca go on with the library, but I'd prefer not to import third-party libs into my app where possible.

Comment: Which IDP you are using, it looks like IDP is mandating the code_challegen param to be sent by SPA

Answer (score 1):

Authorize Endpoint handle multiple grant types, the way you are sending your request, matched to [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) which needs `code_challenge` parameter during the request.

Try something simpler to make a request like:

```
GET /connect/authorize?
client_id=client1&
scope=openid email api1&
response_type=id_token token&
redirect_uri=https://myapp/callback&
state=abc&
nonce=xyz
```

Read [Authorize Endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of generating a challenge code:

```
private string CreateCodeChallenge()
{
    _codeVerifier = RandomNumberGenerator.CreateUniqueId();
    var sha256 = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Sha256);
    var challengeBuffer = sha256.HashData(
        CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_codeVerifier)));
    byte[] challengeBytes;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(challengeBuffer, out challengeBytes);
    return Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
}
```

Include the code and the method in the request querystring.

[image: set these parameters in the request]

You can generate codes for testing here: https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/

That's as far I've gotten with it but I am shown the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's a parameter required by the [Proof Key for Code Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) standard.

> OAuth 2.0 public clients utilizing the Authorization Code Grant are susceptible to the authorization code interception attack. This specification describes the attack as well as a technique to mitigate against the threat through the use of Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE, pronounced "pixy").